# How to link to another page with a back button within the frame

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, adobe-indesign

I need to have a link to another website with a back button on that website (which I don't own) back to my site.

I initially thought of doing this by using and iFrame and then using z-index to put a div onto of this. However I kept getting the message:

```
Refused to display 'url' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'
```

Please note that the user won't have access to the normal back button in the browser so it needs to be in the browser window.

If you know any ways of bypassing the error message above as an alternative that would also really help.

For some context for those of you wondering why (but not needed to solve the question, I don't think) is that I am developing an Indesign panel using CEP.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't own the other website, there is no way to add the back button to it.